# iOS: Storyboard backwards compatible

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4, xcode4.2, storyboard

I created my application with Storyboard not realizing till it was to late that iOS4.3 devices will not be supported. Is there an option where I can copy the storyboard views into xibs or programmatically do it at runtime? What options do I have without completely starting over?

Kinda makes storyboards useless since alot of people still use iOS4x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you bought an iPhone 3G, the day before the 3GS came out, or bought remaining stock in the following weeks, your 20 month upgrade would be available in February 2011.
That gives all the 3G owners almost the last 12 months to have upgraded to a device that supports iOS 5.
So based on those dates, I wouldn't worry about iOS 4.x anymore and only develop for iOS 5.

Just my two coppers.

db

Answer (score 2):

If it's a universal app, the benefits of storyboard are too good to pass up. If someone wants your app, they'll upgrade to 5.x