# Its fine programing for ios4?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios5, ios4

i have a question about a very hard development thing: its okay choose ios4 sdk for startig a project with all the cool things in ios5? And with new iPad in the market?

Thanks

Comment: this is not the right type of question for stack overflow, please see the first two sections of the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use iOS 4 SDK to build apps, if you like. However, those apps won't be able to use any of the new features in iOS 5.

It's better to use the latest version of the development tools, you can always set the target build to a lower OS version if you like.

Comment: Ok, but for example once simple new cool thing in IOS5 are storyboards, but these are not supported in IOS4.

Comment: @returnvoid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404893/ios-storyboard-backwards-compatible